# Windows 10 still loading with a dotted spinner and a black screen

Tags: windows-10

I have faced this problem after upgrading my windows 10 to the last version of these days, after that i have used the computer to do somethings then i have sutted it down. After one day, I tried to start the operation system but I have failed !

The problem is: when i press on the power button the windows logo appers then redirects me to a black screen with a white dotted loading spinner !

It still loading without results, so I described to search about the problem on the internet to fix it, then I tried to repare the system using the windows installation disk (dvd) but didn't works , then I tried to unplug every USBs are plugged in my laptp then restarted the system but it's the same!

So what can I do in this case ? Help me please with a useful steps to fix this problem without deleting anything of my hard disk.

Or is there a method to move a folder in the C partition to a USB memory or burn it to a disk ?

What i want is either fixing the problem or moving the important files I need in my case.

Thanks all

Comment: Did you try to go back to the previous build? In Troubleshoot > Advanced Options [link](https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/windows-10-advanced-startup-options-menu)

Comment: Yes, But it says that my operation system doesn't have this feature !